# When was eleven players per team decided upon?

Tags: rules, football, history

A football team must consist of no more than eleven players (and a minimum of seven). When was this number chosen and is there any reason for it?

Comment: People started trying out the game, and that number (and field size) became the most played.  Some sports are played with different numbers on a similar field (such as tennis and volleyball).  While the size/numbers certainly have something to do with the speed of the ball/object and player movement, can't imagine there's any too-straightforward formula for it.

Comment: @JeopardyTempest that means we may see change in number of player as game evolve, with no specific method or formula.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From this article [Players in a football team](http://www.enfocamp.com/newsletter/2013/en/answers/11-players-football-team.html) we can get some hypotheses:

> The big change arrived in 1870 with the agreement of the regulations that, amongst other things, established that there should only be one goalkeeper who stayed in a fixed position. Similarly it was decided that the number of players should be 11. The reason why this particular number was chosen is not exactly clear: **it is believed that after many trials and tests the conclusion was reached that 20 players were enough to cover the pitch** and to this it was necessary to add the two goalkeepers previously mentioned.
>
> For other people the reason behind it is a lot simpler: **the football team managers wanted their sport to be as popular as or more popular than the most famous at that time, cricket, so they copied the number of players.**

It is indeed interesting to note that many sports have [11 players per team](https://www.factmonster.com/sports/sports-section/official-numbers-players-team): American football, field hockey, cricket...